IBM Websphere scripting SSL configuration
I'm trying to script SSL configuration of IBM websphere, I've managed most of it - but need to set the following using wsadmin.bat or any other sort of scripting.
I need to set the specific SSL configuration against the 'SSL_4' transport channel name
IBM Websphere Web container transport chains config - SSL_4
Any advice for configuring this via script / automation very much appreciated
